# RXjs - flatMap then "merge" it again

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs

I am learning RXjs and I want to understand how things work. So that's why I envisioned a scenario where I make `Observable.of` and pass in an array. I know, `Observable.from` would be more appropriate, but I'm learning how things work.

So, here's my code:

```
let sourceZero = Rx.Observable
                    .of([{name: 'James', age: 25}, {name: 'Angelina', age: 30}]);

sourceZero.subscribe(
  x =>  console.log(x)
);
```

This works as expected: the subscribed value is array.

OK, so now I want to filter that array. While I know there are many other choices I can do that, e.g. in the subscribe part of the code, I want to filter it when creating observable. So, I used `flatMap`, like this.

```
let source = Rx.Observable
              .of([{name: 'James', age: 25}, {name: 'Angelina', age: 30}])
              .flatMap(x => x)
              .filter(x => x.age > 15)
```

While this does what I want, the result is not array anymore, but a stream of objects.

Now, my question is, how do I make an array out of this filtered data again? I don't want to pass single objects to the subscribe part, but an array, as was the case in the first example.

So, the result currently is:

```
[object Object] {
  age: 25,
  name: "James"
}
[object Object] {
  age: 30,
  name: "Angelina"
}
```

But I want it to be:

```
[[object Object] {
  age: 25,
  name: "James"
}, [object Object] {
  age: 30,
  name: "Angelina"
}]
```

Basically, I'm looking for a way to reverse `flatMap`. I used `.concatMap(x => Rx.Observable.of(x))` to no avail.

The code is available here: http://jsbin.com/lujeqowofi/1/edit

Comment: No, currently I do receive objects, i want those objects merged into one array and pass it into the subscribe part. So, the "next" part in subscribe should be called only once and provide array. Now it is called twice, for each object.

Comment: did you found an good answer?

Answer (score 3):

`Reduce`operator is what you are looking for:

```
let source = Rx.Observable
              .of([{name: 'James', age: 25}, {name: 'Angelina', age: 30}])
              .flatMap(x => x)
              .reduce((acc, x) => (acc instanceof Array) ? acc.push(x): [acc, x]);
```

Comment: interestingly enough, if you have `, 1)` part, the result is 3. I guess it's the length of array? I had to omit the `, 1)` part to get it to work properly, here's the code: http://jsbin.com/fudemivoyi/1/edit so what's the last parameter suppose to do?

Comment: Sorry, I answered too quick and I couldn't see the argument. The second argument is the initial accumulator value.

Comment: reduce has also second argument that is initial value for acc. you can avoid checking if it is array or not but setting [] as a initial value: `.reduce((acc, x) => [...acc, x], [])`

Comment: Btw, in your reduce callback `acc.push(x)` will return latest pushed value only, instead of full array

Answer (score 2):

I think you're misunderstanding what RxJS is about. Maybe if I walk you through what your code is doing, you'll see how you went wrong.

```
let source = Rx.Observable
              .of([{name: 'James', age: 25}, {name: 'Angelina', age: 30}])  // 1.
              .flatMap(x => x)  // 2. 
              .filter(x => x.age > 15)  // 3.
```

The key abstraction of Observable is that it's a "stream of values over time". By that we mean that observables emit single values, one value at a time. Those values being emitted may be complex objects or even arrays, but they are still single values.

In your code, when you said Observable.of()  (step 1), you made an observable that can only emit a single value: your array.

Then, when you flatMapped (step 2), you did something i don't think you meant to do. The flatMap operator is meant to work with an Observable that emits Observables as its values. However, in your step 2, your original observable isn't emitting observables, it's emitting an array. But, flatMap is able to convert an array into an observable, so that's what it did.

But at this point, you now have an observable that will emit 2 values: first -> `{name: 'James', age:25 }` and then --> `{name: 'Angelina', age: 30}`. At this point, your observable is no longer dealing with arrays. It's dealing with individual objects.

If your aim is just to filter your original array to only include items that have an age > 15, then use a map on your array.

Comment: thanks for the explanation - that is EXACTLY what I intended to do. Why? Because Angular2 (I put angular2 in the tags as well) returns with `http.get` actually one observable that's array. Not values, but an array of values and that gets streamed when subscribing. I found that odd as well at first.

Comment: Are you passing the result of the http.get to your flatMap directly? It's important to differentiate if your flatMap is getting the Observable<Array> or getting the Array as its parameter because as you now see, you'll get different results. Maybe update your question to reflect what you're actually trying to do to add some more context?

Comment: I'm just learning, there's no project or anything. I figured it would be easier to just understand RXjs a bit before getting to Angular2, so I will know what I am doing. Basically I emulated the results of the http.get request and wanted to filter it. Yes, I know, I could do that in the `.map` part as follows. `.map(x => x.filter(y => y.age > 25))` but I was wondering if when using flatMap, I can stream one array to subscribe function, and that can be achieved with `reduce` as Serginho suggested.

Comment: I guess it works technically. But why convert an Observable<Array<object>> into an observable<object>, apply filter to it and then convert it back to an Observable<Array<object> again? I mean, i guess i understand your point of trying to understand RxJS but to me, that's just extra gymnastics for the sake of gymnastics. To me, understanding RxJS is also about understanding how to use it properly. But i'm an old fogey so maybe i don't understand

Comment: yes, calling this "gymnastics" would be an understatement. I know what I'm doing is not meant to be done, but that's how I learn I suppose - by doing weird things, so that I can understand the underlying behaviour. I even provided the correct approach. I just wanted to know if you can do flatMap, can you reverse it? And obviously you can.

Comment: Isn't this code really not as bad as you say? If this were applied to more complex situations, you could really get something similar to callback hell.

Answer (score 0):

To add on to @Serginho's answer, it might be cleaner to use an empty array as the `seed` (first value)

```
const toArray = reduce((acc, x) => {
    acc.push(x);
    return acc;
}, Array<any>());
```